# Tkinter: Separating Processes

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

I am trying to build a Tkinter program that supports multiprocessing. I need to read from multiple Modbus devices and display the output onto the GUI.

I have successfully done this with a command line by using processes, but in Tkinter, my GUI freezes every time I attempt to read.

Here is my code:

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Process
import threading
import queue
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import time as ttt
import minimalmodbus
import serial
minimalmodbus.CLOSE_PORT_AFTER_EACH_CALL = True


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.gas = minimalmodbus.Instrument('COM3', 1)
        self.gas.serial.baudrate = 9600
        self.gas.serial.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
        self.gas.serial.bytesize = 8
        self.gas.serial.stopbits = 1
        self.gas.serial.timeout = 0.25
        self.gas.mode = minimalmodbus.MODE_RTU

        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.first_gas_labelframe = LabelFrame(self, text="Gas 1", width=100)
        self.first_gas_labelframe.pack()

        self.value_label = Label(self.first_gas_labelframe, text="Value")
        self.value_label.pack()

        self.unit_label = Label(self.first_gas_labelframe, text="Unit")
        self.unit_label.pack()

        self.temp_label = Label(self.first_gas_labelframe, text="Temp")
        self.temp_label.pack()


        self.timer_button = tk.Button(self, text='Start', command=self.process)

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=root.destroy)
        self.quit.pack()

        self.gas_list = [self.gas]

    def reader():
        self.read = gas_num.read_registers(0,42)
        self.value_label.config(text=self.read[0])
        self.unit_label.config(text=self.read[1])
        self.temp_label.config(text=self.read[2])

    def process(self):
        for sen in self.gas_list:
                self.proc = Process(target=self.reader, args=(sen,))
                self.proc.start()
                self.proc.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
        root = tk.Tk()
        app = Application()
        app.mainloop()
```

When I press the start button the program will freeze until the process is done. How do I correctly set up a system to have the GUI operational while having processes run?

Comment: Here is an example of using threads to poll multiple sensors: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44551951/7432 (though, with just a stub for the actual sensor measurement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to put this all on a separate thread. The reason your GUI freezes up is because the `process` method has consumed the Main Thread and until it completes, Tkinter won't update anything.

Here's a simple example:

```
self.timer_button = tk.Button(self, text='Start', command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=self.process).start())
```

However, this doesn't stop the user from clicking the button twice. You could create a new method which controls this. Example:

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Process
import threading
import queue
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import time as ttt
import minimalmodbus
import serial
minimalmodbus.CLOSE_PORT_AFTER_EACH_CALL = True
THREAD_LOCK = threading.Lock()

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.gas = minimalmodbus.Instrument('COM3', 1)
        self.gas.serial.baudrate = 9600
        self.gas.serial.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
        self.gas.serial.bytesize = 8
        self.gas.serial.stopbits = 1
        self.gas.serial.timeout = 0.25
        self.gas.mode = minimalmodbus.MODE_RTU

        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.first_gas_labelframe = LabelFrame(self, text="Gas 1", width=100)
        self.first_gas_labelframe.pack()

        self.value_label = Label(self.first_gas_labelframe, text="Value")
        self.value_label.pack()

        self.unit_label = Label(self.first_gas_labelframe, text="Unit")
        self.unit_label.pack()

        self.temp_label = Label(self.first_gas_labelframe, text="Temp")
        self.temp_label.pack()


        self.timer_button = tk.Button(self, text='Start', command=self.start_thread)

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=root.destroy)
        self.quit.pack()

        self.gas_list = [self.gas]

    def check_thread(self):
        if self.thread.is_alive():
            root.after(50, self.check_thread)
        else:
            # Thread completed
            self.timer_button.config(state='normal')

    def start_thread(self):
        self.timer_button.config(state='disabled')
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.process)
        self.thread.start()
        root.after(50, self.check_thread)

    def reader(self):
        self.read = gas_num.read_registers(0,42)
        self.value_label.config(text=self.read[0])
        self.unit_label.config(text=self.read[1])
        self.temp_label.config(text=self.read[2])

    def process(self):
        with THREAD_LOCK:
            for sen in self.gas_list:
                self.proc = Process(target=self.reader, args=(sen,))
                self.proc.start()
                self.proc.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application()
    app.mainloop()
```

The `Lock` is to ensure no two threads are running at the same time. I've also disables the button so that the user can't click until it's done. By using the `root.after` method, you can create callbacks that wait for a period of time before running.

As far as the multiprocessing, you are running the processes on a separate process, but only one at a time. If you want to run many at one time, then you need to move the `join` call somewhere else. I'm not sure how many processes are running at once but you could do something like this:

```
processes = []
for sen in self.gas_list:
    proc = Process(target=self.reader, args=(sen,))
    processes.append(proc)
    proc.start()
[x.join() for x in processes]
```

In this implementation, I've removed assigning `proc` as a class variable.

I do not have the libraries or data to properly test all this, but it should work...

## EDIT

This will initiate a pool of 6 processes that loop through `self.gas_list`, passing the item to `self.reader`. When those complete, it will check to make sure a second has gone by (waiting if it hasn't) and restarting the above process. This will run forever or until an exception is raised. You will need to import `Pool` from the multiprocessing module.

```
def process(self):
    with THREAD_LOCK:
        pool = Pool(6)
        while 1:
            start_time = time.time()
            pool.map(self.reader, self.gas_list)
            execution_time = time.time() - start_time
            if execution_time < 1:
                time.sleep(1-execution_time)
```

Comment: Great answer, very helpful! Now, I need to fun the process every second, and I will need to have 6 processes all together, is this achievable?

Comment: @Evan Sure, it should be. But I need more information first. Is this in a constant loop of initiating one process per second? Approximately how long does a process take?

Comment: I have 6 devices that need to read about 42 values per cycle. Each device should take less than a second to do so (devices read very quickly) and I want them to read again in a second.

Comment: I am getting the following error: `TypeError: can't pickle _tkinter.tkapp objects`

Comment: @Evan There are a couple things missing from your code and I can't tell what's going on. The reader method should be receiving a variable. One other thing that I haven't gone over is the sharing of variables during multithreading and or multiprocessing. This can cause problems if not taken care of. I would like to see the full traceback in order to see at what point it's breaking.

Comment: @Evan, your error is ok. `Pickle` can serialize only python objects, just don't point that thing on `tk`-related stuff.